# Using skipRedraw in R {rgl} when rotating plot3d

Tags: r, rgl

I am not an R pro, self-taught- thank you for your help!

I have figured out the following code to my satisfaction, which gives me a 3d plot of my data and I can automatically rotate it. However, I want to stop the automatic redraw of the axes as it spins. I have found many resources using par3d(skipRedraw=TRUE) but I cannot figure out how to incorporate it into my code, it is all a bit beyond me.

Also, (I was going to give up on this one but since I'm asking anyway) I'd also like to be able to have the axes labels stay next to the axis tick marks (rather than across from it/on the other side). But this is secondary.

Thank you in advance!

```
mydata<-read.csv(file=file.choose(),header=TRUE,row.names=1)
mydata$Colour<-factor(mydata$ColourB,levels=c("Black","Blue","Red","Green","Yellow","Purple","Brown"))
colourb<-as.character(mydata$ColourB)
library(rgl)
open3d()
plot3d(mydata[,"Sr"],
   mydata[,"Rb"],
   mydata[,"Zr"],
   xlab="Sr (ppm)",
   ylab="Rb (ppm)",
   zlab="Zr (ppm)",
   pch=21,
   col=colourb,
   type="s",
   radius=10
)
bgplot3d({
  plot.new()
  title(main = 'Trace Elements', line = 1)
})
play3d(spin3d(axis=c(0,0,1), rpm=10), duration=10)
```

Comment: The second part of your question is answered here:  <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604828/how-to-move-axis-labels-automatically-in-rgl-r>.  It's not easy.  I'm not sure what you want to happen, and your code can't be run by others, so I can't help with the first part.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to stop the automatic redraw of the axes. When you use bbox-axes (default), they are redrawn. So you just use fixed position axes. (EDITED: I might misunderstand your quiestion.)

Here is my example (using data `trees`):

```
open3d()
plot3d(trees, type="s", radius=0.4, col="red", xlab="xxx", ylab="yyy", zlab="zzz", 
       axes=F) # not use bbox-axes
axes3d(edges = c("x","y","z")) # draw fixed position axes
box3d()                        # if you need, draw full box

bgplot3d({
  plot.new()
  title(main = 'Trees', line = 1)
})
play3d(spin3d(axis=c(0,0,1), rpm=10), duration=10)


# PS: skipRedraw isn't what you think.
plot3d(trees)
par3d(skipRedraw = T) # you can't turn the graph by drag
```

Comment: I don't think that is actually what the OP wants to do. I think having the object spinning inside the box without it moving is what is desired.

Comment: Before answering, I should have learned manners. Thank you for letting me realize it !!! As for your first comment, I can’t say for sure..., but you may be right.

Comment: He is not clear, but otherwise it would be too easy. I think one might be able to modify `par3dinterp` to interpolate the modeling matrix to do this, but have not gotten around to trying that.

Comment: @Mike Wise Thanks again.  If I do the object spinning inside the box without it moving, I'll use plot3d( ~, axes=F) and bgplot3d( persp( ~, ticktype = "detailed", border=NA, col=""white" ) ).